# Kmeans, failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4:...)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

I try to apply kmeans algorithm.

**Code**

```
val dfJoin_products_items = df_products.join(df_items, "product_id")
dfJoin_products_items.createGlobalTempView("products_items")
val weightFreight = spark.sql("SELECT cast(product_weight_g as double) weight, cast(freight_value as double) freight FROM global_temp.products_items")
case class Rows(weight:Double, freight:Double)
val rows = weightFreight.as[Rows]
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("weight", "freight")).setOutputCol("features")
val data = assembler.transform(rows)
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(4)
val model = kmeans.fit(data)
```

**Values**

*dfJoin_products_items*

```
scala> dfJoin_products_items.printSchema
root
 |-- product_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_category_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_name_lenght: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_description_lenght: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_photos_qty: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_weight_g: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_length_cm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_height_cm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_width_cm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order_item_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- seller_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- shipping_limit_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)
 |-- freight_value: string (nullable = true)
```

*weightFreight*

```
scala> weightFreight.printSchema
root
 |-- weight: double (nullable = true)
 |-- freight: double (nullable = true)
```

**Error**

```
2019-02-03 20:51:41 WARN  BlockManager:66 - Putting block rdd_126_1 failed due to exception org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (struct<weight:double,freight:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>).
2019-02-03 20:51:41 WARN  BlockManager:66 - Block rdd_126_1 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
2019-02-03 20:51:41 WARN  BlockManager:66 - Putting block rdd_126_2 failed due to exception org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (struct<weight:double,freight:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>).
2019-02-03 20:51:41 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 1.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 23)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$4: (struct<weight:double,freight:double>) => struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>)
```

I don't understand this error, someone can explain me please ?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE 1 : Full stacktrace**

The stacktrace is huge, so you can find it here : https://pastebin.com/PhmZPtDk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SparkException: Values to assemble cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362295/sparkexception-values-to-assemble-cannot-be-null)

Comment: I already tried, but I still have the same error.