# Convert a string to logical in R with sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have 100 million rows stored in many .csv files in a distributed file system.  I'm using spark_read_csv() to load the data without issue.  Many of my columns are stored as character logical values: `"true"`, `"false"`, `"<na>"`.  I do not have control over this.

When I attempt to convert the values to logical, the `"<na>"` values are converted to `FALSE` with the `"false"` values.  Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

```
test_lgl <- 
  tibble(a = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE),
         b = c("true", "true", "na", "<na>", "false", "f"))

test_lgl %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.logical)

# this works
   a     b
  <lgl> <lgl>
1  TRUE  TRUE
2  TRUE  TRUE
3    NA    NA
4    NA    NA
5 FALSE FALSE
6 FALSE    NA

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
spark_lgl <- copy_to(sc, test_lgl)

spark_lgl %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.logical)

# this does not
      a     b
  <lgl> <lgl>
1  TRUE  TRUE
2  TRUE  TRUE
3 FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE
5 FALSE FALSE
6 FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: not directly related but ... https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I attempt to convert the values to logical, the `"<na>"` values are converted to `FALSE`

Surprisingly there are not. If you inspect the result further:

```
spark_lgl_boolean <- spark_lgl %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.logical)
spark_lgl_boolean %>% mutate_all(is.na)

Applying predicate on the first 100 rows
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
      a     b
  <lgl> <lgl>
1 FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE  TRUE
4  TRUE  TRUE
5 FALSE FALSE
6 FALSE FALSE
```

This is consistent with [NA count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47512964/6910411):

```
spark_lgl_boolean %>%
  mutate_all(is.na) %>% 
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  summarize_all(sum)
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     2
```

Spark [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614889/8371915):

```
spark_lgl %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.logical) %>% optimizedPlan
```

```
Applying predicate on the first 100 rows
<jobj[1074]>
  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project
  Project [a#10, cast(b#11 as boolean) AS b#2037]
+- InMemoryRelation [a#10, b#11], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas), `test_lgl`
      +- *FileScan csv [a#10,b#11] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/tmp/..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<a:boolean,b:string>
```

and Spark casting logic for `StringType` -> `BooleanType` where:

- Strings `TRUE` / `T` (case insensitive) and `1` are converted to `true` literal.
- Strings `FALSE` / `F` (case insensitive) and `0` are converted to `false` literal.
- Strings not matched above are converted to `NULL` (~`NA`).

```scala
scala> Seq("tRUE", "FALSE", "f", "<na>", "NA", "1", "0").toDF("x").select($"x".cast("boolean")).show
+-----+
|    x|
+-----+
| true|
|false|
|false|
| null|
| null|
| true|
|false|
+-----+
```

Problem seems to be specifically introduced by `sparklyr` conversions. See [Improve Serialization](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/941) on GitHub (credits to [kevinykuo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835778/kevinykuo) for pointing out this one).

However if you stick to Spark based logic, without fetching data to R, things should work just fine (for example if you write data to file).

> I'm using spark_read_csv() to load the data

In that case you might take a look at `nullValue` and `nanValue` `options` of the [CSV reader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@csv(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame). For example:

```
spark_read_csv(..., options=list(nullValue="<na>"))
```

or

```
spark_read_csv(..., options=list(nanValue="<na>"))
```

but please keep in mind, that Spark semantics of `NULL` / `NaN` is not the same as R `NA` / `NaN`.