# replacing "NA" values of a column with mean in spark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file with name and value as my column. Both are in string format.

```
dummy.csv:
Jordan  20|
  Mike   NA|
  James   30|
  Steve   NA|
   Stella   20|
   David   NA

Schema:

root
 name: string (nullable = true)
 value: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to replace "NA" values with average value of that particular column. I'm able to calculate the average,however I have an issue replacing "NA" values with mean

```
dummmyCol=['value']
dummydf.select([round(mean(col(c)),2).alias(c) for c in dummmyCol]).show()

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|23.33|
+-----+
```

The below code is what I attempted to replace NA values. I know the below code is flawed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
dummydf.select([when(col(c1)=='NA',dummydf.select(round(mean(col(c1)),2))).alias(c1) for c1 in dummmyCol])
```

Expected output should be:

```
 Jordan  20|
  Mike   23.3|
  James   30|
  Steve   23.3|
   Stella   20|
   David   23.3
```

Comment: you can see this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057563/replace-missing-values-with-mean-spark-dataframe

Comment: I did go through this. But I'm unwilling to use ml features for this question since I have no idea what imputer does. Are there any chances I can get this done with my approach in python?