# Pyspark - Fill nans with average of previous and next values

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a dataset in which all the columns are numbers and there are some nans I want to fill. The rows must be seen as a temporal serie, so I want to fill those nans with the average of next and previous values. Is there any way to do it in Pyspark?

Thanks!!

Comment: Sample of data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace missing values with mean - Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057563/replace-missing-values-with-mean-spark-dataframe)